# Bigquery: "User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission" with roles/bigquery.admin

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, terraform

Background: I have been developing a backend for the last few days and would like to push some analytic data to Bigquerry using a cloud function triggered by Firestore. I am using Terraform for the deployment.

Problem: The python script works locally with my user account (owner) without any problems. But when I use the cloud function, it cannot perform a query. For some reason, the insert works, but the query does not. I always get the error `User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission` and an exception is thrown, even though the function service account has the permission "roles/bigquery.admin" in the same project.

However, this works (python):

```py
errors = client.insert_rows_json(table_id_users, user_data)
```

But this does not:

```py
query = f"SELECT user_id FROM `project-xyz.analytics.users` WHERE user_id = '{user_id}'"
query_job = client.query(query)
result = list(query_job.result())
```

Terraform Code for the permissions:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset_iam_binding" "editor" {
    dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.default.dataset_id
    role       = "roles/bigquery.admin"

    members = [
        "serviceAccount:${module.my_function_2.service_account_email}",
    ]
}
```

When I click on the permission settings on the bigquerry table, I can see that the service account is listed in the `BigQuery-Administrator` section, which should have the `bigquery.jobs.create` permission.

The service account logs also says that the user account has the permission "bigquery.jobs.create" but in the same log entry the error appears:

```
authorizationInfo: [
0: {
  resource: "projects/project-xyz"
  permission: "bigquery.jobs.create"
  resourceAttributes: {0}
}
]
...
...
status: {
  code: 7, 
  message: "Access Denied: Project higym-ecafb: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project project-xyz."
}
```

For me it looks like everything should be fine and my function has all the permissions to do a query (the insert works), but in the end it does not work.

I also noticed that the service account created with Terraform does not appear in the IAM view. Only on the service accounts page they are visible.

Is there anything else I can try? What are the next steps on how I can debug this problem?
Maybe i have overlooked something fundamental.

Thank You for your help!

**Edit**:
I found the problem. In teraform the role must be specified for iam and bigquery. Only one of them is not enough.

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset_iam_member" "admin" {
    dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.default.dataset_id
    role       = "roles/bigquery.admin"

    member = "serviceAccount:${module.my_function_2.service_account_email}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "admin" {
    project = var.project_id
    role       = "roles/bigquery.admin"
    member = "serviceAccount:${module.my_function_2.service_account_email}"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work correctly, you have to be sure the service account that is admin of the `BigQuery` table, is also correctly assigned to the `Cloud Function`.

The `Cloud Function` should have the right to execute the needed action on your resources.

You can check that in the `Cloud Function` details tab :

[image]

Comment: Yes, they are identical. I have edited my original question and added the images. That should be the correct configuration?

Comment: Are you sure you added the role to the expected dataset ? Have you also tried to set this role to the SA in IAM (in all datasets) instead of on your dataset for testing purpose ?

Comment: yes, and somehow it works with this permission because the cloud function can insert data. Only when I do a query, this error appears. I will transfer the complete project to a new account and hope it will work there. Maybe there is a bug or a resource error. 


Another Question: All service accounts created with Terraform are not visible in the IAM Overview page. Only in the service account menu I can see them. But there I can not list all permissions.... Is that normal?

Comment: Normally in the IAM menu, if you set roles to the SA, it should appear.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. The policy document was known only to bigquery, but not in IAM itself.

Comment: You’re welcome, if my answer helped you, can you mark it as solved please ?